# Source command not working through Java

Tags: java, python, bash, terminal

From last day, I have been trying to execute a command on Terminal (MAC) using JAVA but whatever I do nothing is working.

I have the following 2 commands that I want to execute and get the output back in JAVA

```
source activate abc_env
python example.py
```

Till now, I have tried the following methods without any output

```
String[] command = new String[] { "source activate abc_env", "python example.py"};
String result = executeCommands(command);
```

Here is my executeCommands method

```
private static String executeCommands(String[] command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            for(int i=0; i< command.length;i++)
            {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command[i]);
                p.waitFor();
                BufferedReader reader = 
                                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                String line = "";           
                while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                    output.append(line + "\n");
                }
                System.out.println("Error output: " + p.exitValue());
                System.out.println("Output:" + output);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Here");
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

This gives me the following exception

> Cannot run program "source": error=2, No such file or directory

I searched online and people say that source won't work like this and I should change the command to

```
String[] command = new String[] { "bash -c 'source activate abc_env'", "python example.py"};
```

Now, I donot get the exception but the command still does not work and it returns '2' as **exitValue()**

Then I tried to execute the commands as a script

```
#!/bin/bash
source activate abc_env
python example.py
```

I get the following exception when I read the .sh file as string and pass it to command

> Cannot run program "#!/bin/bash": error=2, No such file or directory

So, my question is how to run the source command followed by python command properly through Java ? My final goal is execute some python from Java.

EDIT1:
If I try the following command and print the output stream

```
String[] command = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "source activate cvxpy_env"
        };

executeCommand(command));
```

Output Stream:

> ExitValue:1
>
> ErrorOutput:/bin/bash: activate: No such file or directory

If I try the same command but with single quotes around 'source activate abc_env'. I get the following output

> ExitValue:127
>
> ErrorOutput:/bin/bash: source activate cvxpy_env: command not found

Solution:

```
String[] command = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "source /Users/pc_name/my_python_library/bin/activate abc_env;python example.py"
        };
```

Comment: To make it even more clear, this "/Users/pc_name/my_python_library/bin/activate/" in linux could be translated to the path where Anaconda is installed, such as: "/opt/anaconda/bin/activate". Thus:
`source /opt/anaconda/bin/activate abc_env` (if abc_env is your environment's name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Javadoc, `Runtime.exec(String)` breaks the command into the command-args list using a `StringTokenizer`, which will probably break your command into:

```
bash
-c
'source
activate
abc_env'
```

Which is obviously not what you want. What you should do is probably use the version of `Runtime.exec(String[])` that accepts a ready list of arguments, passing to it `new String[] {"bash", "-c", "source activate abc_env"}`.

Now, to get an idea why it's not working, you should not only read from its `stdout` but also from `stderr`, using `p.getErrorStream()`. Just print out what you read, and it will be a great debugging aid.

Re: your edit. Now it looks like it's working fine, as far as Java and bash are concerned. The output "activate: No such file or directory" is probably the output from the successful run of the `source` command. It just that `source` can't find the `activate` file. Is it in the working directory? If not, you probably should have `"cd /wherever/your/files/are; source activate cvxpy_env"`. Oh, and if your python script depends on whatever side-effects the source command has, you probably have to execute it in the same `bash` instance, that is:

```
String[] command = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "cd /wherever/your/files/are && source activate cvxpy_env && python example.py"
        };
```

Or better yet, pack it all into a single shell script, and then just `Runtime.exec("./my_script.sh")` (don't forget to `chmod +x` it, though).

Comment: I tried the things you mentioned but I still have an error. I have updated my question. Kindly see EDIT1.

Comment: Ok great. I will try your new answer and will update u soon. Going for a meeting.

Comment: Great. I got it working. I just included the path of activate script and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] command = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "source activate abc_env; " + "python example.py"
        };
```

Comment: See EDIT1. I tried the thing that you mentioned but still I have errors.

Comment: @Behroz You might need to specify the full path of your 'activate' and 'abc_env' scripts as well as 'example.py'. The error is telling you that it cannot find the file.

Comment: /bin/bash <---- this is what i get after whereis

Comment: String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash" , "-c",  "cd  /zookeeper/bin" + "./zkCli.sh"};
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
            pr.waitFor();

            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
               System.out.println(line);
            }
whats wrong in this